# Открытие файла посредством задания полного пути до файла

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Пытаюсь сделать программу, которая будет открывать нужный файл таким способом:
В одно поле пользователь вводит полный путь к файлу, а при нажатии на кнопку, программа считывает этот путь и создает объект класса FileReader с этим путем и считывает текст из этого файла. Проблема заключается в том, что всегда выбрасывается FileNotFoundException. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Может у вас разрешений нужных нет в манифесте или вы их программно не запросили у юзера на 6 версии андроида?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле AndroidManifest.xml нужно прописать такие строки для получения доступа к чтению `<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать FileNotFoundException предварительно проверяйте, действительно ли существует файл по указанному пути. Делать это можно с помощью метода [exists() объекта класса File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists()).

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
    // открываем файл для чтения
}
```